# Disabling delete listitem clientside

Tags: list-item, delete, related-list

I added a `Related Item View` to a `Displayform`, as standard there is the `Select all` flag/button. In order to deny the user from deleting a listitem I'd like to remove this button. Is there a way to do it? If No, is it possible to override the javascript function in order to define a custom behavior?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the column with the checkbox from the view?

Comment: If it's possible, yes...

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Based on the new information provided, I'm updating this answer.

**New Answer**

You can disable the checkmarks for items by modifying the list view. In the `Library` or `List` tab, click `Modify View` to open the view settings for the list. About half-way down the settings page expand the `Tabular View` setting and then uncheck the `Allow individual item checkboxes` setting. Click `Ok` to save your changes.

**Old Answer**

You can achieve this by creating a custom permission level in SharePoint where the ability to delete items is removed from the user. If you still want the user to be able to add and edit items, make a copy of the out of the box `Contribute` permission level called `NoDelete` (or something like that). Then edit the `NoDelete` permission level and remove the `Delete Items` permission.

Comment: Hi, thaks for the reply. I already know this solution, but what i want is to disable the deletion only in a view, not for all views. Thath's why i want do remove the single column from the view...

Answer (score -1):

how to handle the delete icon on list item selection (enabling/ disabling) based on the logged in user using CSOM/REST API services using jQuery

follow the below url

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-how-to-unabledisable-delete-icon-in-ribbon/